# The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, wsl-2

I'm trying to run docker-compose build and I've got this issue:

```
=> ERROR [ 3/12] RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client libpng12-0                                                        1.7s
------
 > [ 3/12] RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client libpng12-0:
#6 1.665 W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
#6 1.665 E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client libpng12-0]: exit code: 100
```

This is Ubuntu 18.04 with WSL2 on Windows 10.

**What does it mean that 'The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed.'?**
Is this the main problem?

When I try to do this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553
```

I get this:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Vdb8SgvVbt/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553
gpg: key 8B48AD6246925553: 30 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 8B48AD6246925553: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

And after this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client libpng12-0
```

I get the info that I have the newest version:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-client is already the newest version (10+190ubuntu0.1).
nodejs is already the newest version (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4).
libpng12-0 is already the newest version (1.2.54-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 166 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside your `Dockerfile` file please add:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553 7638D0442B90D010 CBF8D6FD518E17E1
```

before the line with:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client libpng12-0
```

Comment: This worked for this error on ftp.debian.org but why?
How did you find out the command and the values?

Comment: values are from ubuntu forum and another resources :)

Comment: @RichardBarraclough values are taken from error log which you can see in the question.

Comment: `RUN` is not needed on Ubuntu 20. Just `apt-get  update -qq...`

Answer (score 2):

I think there can be another solution [according to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209266/487594) to add this layer before apt-get update

```
RUN apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```

A bit better because *it does not install debian-keyring, which is big and 99% of the time unnecessary*